# Better way to store unsorted pairs in sql database

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, database-design

Data looks like this:

unsorted pair `(x,y)` (two locations) + value (distance between this two locations)

```
A B 4
A C 13
B C 1
```

My question is what is the best way to keep this in a SQL database? I can keep this as is (unsorted). Then if I want to determine how far is point B from every other location from database (in other words, values for every pair which contains B) I need to look in both columns (let's assume their names are `x` and `y`).

```
select * 
from table 
where x = B or y = B
```

On the other hand if I keep this like this:

```
A B 4
A C 13
B A 4
B C 1
C A 13
C B 1
```

then my query is simple

```
select * 
from table 
where x = B
```

but the size of data is twice as much. Any other ideas? Any other technology (mongodb)?

Comment: What's the problem with the first query? And which DBMS are you planning to use? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You might want to try asking this in English. What is the difference between the first and second sample? I don't see one. I see references to "X" and "Y" without any properties specified as "X" or "Y". And I also see a theoretical example that makes it hard for people to understand the real problem you are facing. In experience, very few people present a theoretical example that truly represents the real problem they are facing. Thus they get the wrong solution.

Comment: There is no difference between this two samples. Both samples represent the same data, but in different ways.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres probably.

Comment: You could store both locations in an array column and use `'b' = any(x)` to search it (that can even be supported by an index). Using an array has a lot of disadvantages though: you can't have foreign keys and if you also access each location individually that might get ugly as well.  I'm not sure if that really is a viable solution though. Plus: I still don't see the problem with the first query.

Comment: Distance between two points is not necessarily symmetric, as anyone who has lived in Boston knows.  Seriously, direct distance is symmetric, but anything based on routes on the ground (or even in the air) may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really about locations and distances, and not just a hypothetical example, I feel it would make sense to store the data as mentioned in the second scenario, since in the real world, the distance from A to B does not necessarily have to be the same as the distance from B to A, if you consider one-way roads or other such reasons.

On the other hand, if you consider the distance to be ["as the crow flies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_crow_flies), you might want to consider Spatial Data Types, as available [natively in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx). I am no good with Postgres, but find that the same is available through [this extender](http://postgis.net/).